# Determine a field of mathematics

Tags: analysis

What field of mathematics answers the question of how often (or how many times) does the function takes a given value? With some conditions, for example at a given interval or in a given area.

Comment: No branch of math tells you that for general functions. Except maybe set theory, but that's basically a tautology. Depending on what kind of functions they are, different branches of math (complex analysis, real analysis, topology, etc) can help.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. If you have a question about a particular function, ask that question and show us your work so far. Then perhaps we can help.

Comment: I would say counting problems are typically combinatorics. It's a vague and large discipline that intersects with essentially every other area of mathematics.

Comment: pretty sure that's algebra

Answer (score 1):

No one field of mathematics can give you the answer, because a "function" is an extremely general concept. It is merely a mapping between two sets, and these sets are not specified to be anything; so functions come up basically everywhere in mathematics, and everywhere that it does come up, there can be some use for counting how many times it takes a given value.

In elementary calculus for instance, the question of how many times a differentiable function $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ attains a critical point is usually considered by looking at how many times its derivative attains the value of $0$. This consideration is crucial in basic optimisation problems of the form "find the maximum/minimum value of the function $f(x)$ on the interval $I$".

Then in group theory, the functions one looks at are homomorphisms between groups, and here counting problems are of interest as well. For example, the isomorphism theorems for groups imply that if we have a surjective homomorphism $G\to H$ for groups $G,H$, then an equal number of elements in $G$ is mapped to each element in $H$, giving the formula $|G|=[G:H]|H|$ where $[G:H]$ is the index of $H$ in $G$. This theme is recurrent in algebra more generally: for instance, in linear algebra one considers maps between vector spaces and asks about their dimensions, which in some sense is fundamentally also about how often the map attains a certain value.

What I gave above are nothing but an incomplete list of examples. In fact, one could be reasonably confident that given any field of math, there is going to be some way in which counting problems of the form "for $f:A\to B$, find the number of $a\in A$ so that for given $b\in B$, $f(a)=b$" is crucial to study. No one field of math answers this question: it is so general that it is important basically everywhere.